# Duplicate All single rows in database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, not-exists

I have this table with multiple columns. Primary key is `(type,ref,code)` with row type `t1`, `t2`, and two states Valid `(V)` and Invalid `(I)`.

Every invalid row in state `t1` should have a valid row in the state `t2`,
but my table already has some rows with Invalid state that don't have the valid row in the state `t2`.

Example:

```
   type    |  ref   |  code   | state .....
----------------------------------------
   t1      |  1     | c1      | V
   t1      |  2     | c1      | V
   t1      |  3     | c1      | I
   t2      |  3     | c1      | V
   t1      |  4     | c1      | V
   t1      |  5     | c1      | I
```

so i need to duplicate the missing rows

I'm using

```
INSERT INTO table (type,ref,code,state)
SELECT 't2',ref,code,'V' FROM table
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ref,code,count(*) from table GROUP BY ref,code HAVING count(*)=1)
AND state='I'
```

but I'm getting

```
 Violation of PRIMARY KEY
```

I tried with

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ref,code,count(*) from table GROUP BY ref,code HAVING count(*)>1)
AND state='I'
```

and nothing hapend. Any dea how to perform this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query to get to-be-duplicated rows:

```
SELECT type, ref, code, state
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE state = 'I' AND type = 't1' AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable AS t2
                  WHERE t1.ref = t2.ref AND t1.code = t2.code AND
                        state = 'V' AND type = 't2')
```

So, the `INSERT` statement can look like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable 
SELECT 't2', ref, code, 'V'
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE state = 'I' AND type = 't1' AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable AS t2
                  WHERE t1.ref = t2.ref AND t1.code = t2.code AND
                        state = 'V' AND type = 't2')
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a primary key, must be unique and not null for definition. so if you need two or more states you need another table, or another field(if just two) but than get seek to query

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
  INSERT INTO #TAB
  SELECT 't2', REF, CODE, 'V' FROM #TAB WHERE stateS='I' 
  AND REF NOT IN (SELECT REF FROM #TAB WHERE stateS='V' AND typeSS='T2')
```